# Group rows partially [Python] [Pandas]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, higher-order-functions

0

Good morning everyone.

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

info = {
'states': [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
'values': [34, 29, 28, 30, 35, 33, 33, 36, 40, 41] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=info)

print(df)

>>> 
    states   values
0       -1       34
1       -1       29
2       -1       28
3        1       30
4        1       35
5       -1       33
6        0       33
7        1       36
8        1       40
9        1       41
```

I need to group the data **using PANDAS** (and/or higher order functions) (*already did the exercise using for loops*), I need to group the data having the "states" column as a guide. But the grouping should not be of all the data, I only need to group the data that is neighboring... as follows:

Initial DataFrame:

```
    states   values
0       -1       34 ┐
1       -1       29 │    Group this part (states = -1)
2       -1       28 ┘
3        1       30 ┐    Group this part (states =  1)
4        1       35 ┘
5       -1       33     'Group' this part (states = -1)
6        0       33     'Group' this part (states =  0)
7        1       36 ┐
8        1       40 │    Group this part (states =  1)
9        1       41 ┘
```

It would result in a DataFrame, with a grouping by segments (from the "states" column) and in another column the sum of the data (from the "values" column).

Expected DataFrame:

```
    states   values
0       -1       91     (values=34+29+28)
1        1       65     (values=30+35)
2       -1       33
3        0       33
4        1       117    (values=36+40+41)
```

You who are more versed in these issues, perhaps you can help me perform this operation.

**Thank you so much!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identify the blocks/groups of rows using `diff` and `cumsum` then group the dataframe by these blocks and aggregate `states` with `first` and `values` with `sum`

```
b = df['states'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.groupby(b).agg({'states': 'first', 'values': 'sum'})
```

Result

```
        states  values
states                
1           -1      91
2            1      65
3           -1      33
4            0      33
5            1     117
```

Comment: Shubham Sharma... thank you very much, your solution is very elegant!

Comment: Do you have any bibliographical reference that you can recommend... where these topics are addressed (I have realized that I need a lot to be able to program like this). Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help @FedericaF. If you are getting started with pandas then I would suggest this [amazing official guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) and rest you can learn by practicing :-)